# Can I embed a YouTube video in a question or answer?

Tags: support, questions, markdown, formatting

Over on [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) I often see YouTube videos embedded in questions and answers. [Here is an example.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/21642/9818)

I see in the source that there is not special markup, just the youtube.com url alone on one line. [I tried that on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/360288/15210) but it doesn't work the same way.

I also tried the standard image markup (`![description](url)`) but that did not work, either.

Is there a way to embed YouTube videos in a question or answer on SuperUser?

Comment: Is there much need for embedding YouTube?

Comment: I assume there is not much need because this question has not been asked before. If the answer is "No" then so be it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YouTube embedding is enabled only at [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and [Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/), IIRC due to the high reliance on videos to show tips etc.

Not available on Super User.

> #### [YouTube and SoundCloud embedding is now enabled](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled)
>
> It is now possible to embed YouTube and SoundCloud content in posts here. […]